# Embedding with 'object' tag not working on dynamic data

Tags: html, angularjs, html-object

I am trying to embed youtube videoes using the object tag instead of iframes. However, it doesn't work even though element.url points to the correct url. If I replace {{element.url}} (in object tag) with just the url, it works just fine. The iframe works as it is.

```
<div ng-show="element.url" id="resourceFrame">      
  <iframe class="iframe" width="500" height="325"  src="{{element.url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <object width="500" height="325" >
    <param
      name="{{element.name}}"
      value="{{element.url}}">
    </param>
    <param
      name="allowscriptaccess"
      value="always">
    </param>
    <param
      name="allowFullScreen"
      value="true">
    </param>
    <embed
      src="{{element.url}}"
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      allowscriptaccess="always"
      allowfullscreen="true"
      width="500"
      height="325">
    </embed>
  </object> 
  <div id="text-content" ng-show="element.text">
    <p>{{element.text}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does {{element.url}} work in iframe, but not object tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been described in many SO questions and answers. In short, as far as I understood correctly, it's because you "execute" remote `<object>`. In this case all `<object>` see as source, is really just literal  `{{ element.url }}`.

You can go around this by creating your own `Youtube directive`. For example:

```
app.directive('youtube', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          movie: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var object = '<object width="560" height="315">' +
              '<param name="movie" value="' + scope.movie + '" />' +
              '<embed ' +
              '  src="' + scope.movie + '" ' +
              '  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ' +
              '  width="560" ' +
              '  height="315" />' +
            '</object>';
            element.replaceWith(object);
        }
    };
});
```

Usage in HTML template would be as simple as

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <youtube movie="{{ movie.url }}"></youtube>
</body>
```

And in controller, you have your movie

```
$scope.movie = { 
    name: 'movie',
    url: '//www.youtube.com/v/YrrzgE8J1KI'
};
```

Example Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/RJyewh which you can continue to improve by adding new attributes (width and so on) as you see appropriate.

Of course you could wrap any other `<object>` in directive, too.