# Angular directive scope eval is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using Angular in our site and am struggling to get directives working correctly. I've got a directive that's attempting to use Flash and a media player to display a video selected by dynamically building object tags and inserting a url at the correct point.

Here's the directive

```js
    app.directive('movie', function() {
      var params = "&autoPlay=true&verbose=true&plugin_AdaptiveStreamingPlugin=http://D28C.wpc.azureedge.net/80D28C/amsplayer/assets/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.13-osmf2.0.swf&amp;AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryLive=true&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryInterval=10";

      return {
        restrict: 'E',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var url = scope.$eval(attrs.src);

          element.replaceWith('<object width="640" height="400" id="flashPlayer" ' +
            'data="http://D28C.wpc.azureedge.net/80D28C/amsplayer/assets/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf" ' +
            'type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"> ' +
            '<param name="wmode" value="direct"> ' +
            '<param name="flashvars" value="src=' + url + params + '">' +
            '</object>');
        }
      };
    });
```

Here's the html

```
 <div>
   <movie src="vm.video.fileUri" />
 </div>
```

In Chrome, when debugging, this line in the directive:

```
          var url = scope.$eval(attrs.src);
```

correctly contains the value **vm.video.fileUri** for attrs.src.
However, when I execute that line - the value is undefined rather than the url of the video that we want to display.

I've tried manually looking for the value by using scope.$parent.$eval in the console window - but can't find the url.  What am I doing wrong???

I'm ending up with the word **undefined** with all the object parameters in the rendered html

thanks

Comment: `vm.video.fileUri` is assigned asyncronously?

Comment: there's a controller that's populating the vm object. When the view renders, that properly should have a value in it.

Comment: try changing restrict:'AE'

Comment: Thanks Chaitanya. However, it's still coming back as undefined.  Why do you think changing **restrict** would work?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to define a local scope in the directive and get its values? It is a recommended way of setting the scope on DDO while creating custom directives. This way we make sure the directive do not interfere with the parent scope.

```
app.directive('movie', function() {
      var params = "&autoPlay=true&verbose=true&plugin_AdaptiveStreamingPlugin=http://D28C.wpc.azureedge.net/80D28C/amsplayer/assets/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.13-osmf2.0.swf&amp;AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryLive=true&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryInterval=10";

      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          src: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var url = scope.src;

          element.replaceWith('<object width="640" height="400" id="flashPlayer" ' +
            'data="http://D28C.wpc.azureedge.net/80D28C/amsplayer/assets/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf" ' +
            'type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"> ' +
            '<param name="wmode" value="direct"> ' +
            '<param name="flashvars" value="src=' + url + params + '">' +
            '</object>');
        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: thanks for this Shankar. I've tried it but scope.src is still undefined.  The function body looks as you've suggested

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same question, I found some kind of answer here:

[Embedding with 'object' tag not working on dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220041/embedding-with-object-tag-not-working-on-dynamic-data)

Hope it helps.